# Show events in month by specific category - Solspace Calendar

Tags: craft3, plugin-solspacecalendar, calendar

I've set up a category field for events. Multiple categories can be chosen. And I've set up a form to "filter" events to a specific category using query parameters.

The URL looks something like this (simplified; region is the category):

```
domain.com/events/month?&region=portland
```

Is there a way to show events that pertain to the category param in the month view?

Been banging my head and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. For anyone else seeing this later on:

```
{% set regionCategory = craft.categories.group('eventRegions').slug(region).one() %}

{% set month = craft.calendar.month({ relatedTo: regionCategory }) %}
```